# How do I prove that $\theta_1 \cup (\theta_1 \circ \theta_2) \cup (\theta_1 \circ \theta_2 \circ \theta_1) \: \cup ...$ is an equivalence relation?

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations, universal-algebra

If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are two equivalence relations, how do I show that

$$\theta_1 \cup (\theta_1 \circ \theta_2) \cup (\theta_1 \circ \theta_2 \circ \theta_1) \: \cup ...$$

is it an equivalence relation too?

My problem is I am not sure what the $\cup$ does with the parentheses. I would certainly use that $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are already equivalence relations, but not sure, how to proceed with the  $\circ$ and $\cup$.

Thank you for any help!

---

The "$\circ$" means relational product:

> the relational product $r\circ s$ of two binary relations $r,s$ on $A$ is given by: $\langle a,b \rangle \in r\circ s$ iff for some $c,\langle a,c \rangle \in r,\langle c,b\rangle \in s$

Comment: A relation in set theory is a set. Thus, the "union" of two (or more) relations is usual set union.

Comment: Giving a bit more detail to Mauro's comment, if $\theta$ is an equivalence relation (or more generally, any binary relation) on a set $X$, then $\theta\subseteq X^2$, and the same applies to $\theta_1\circ\theta_2, \theta_1\circ\theta_2\circ\theta_1,\ldots$ in your displayed formula, so that union is a union of subsets of $X^2$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622205/if-e-1-and-e-2-are-equivalence-relations-is-e-1-circ-e-2-an-equivalence-r)

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Alright, so if $\langle a, b \rangle \in$ the union, then $a$ is in minimally one of the parentheses...  I think it could be much clearer than to prove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Call this union $R$. If $x \in X$ (the set on which the relations "live") then $(x,x) \in \theta_1 \subseteq R$. So $R$ is trivially reflexive.

If $(x,y) \in R$ then either $(x,y)\in \theta_1$ so $(y,x) \in R$ or

$(x,y) \in \theta_1 \circ \theta_2 \circ \ldots \circ \theta_i$ for $i\in \{1,2\}$ and some finite alternating composition. All such finite compositions are sub-equivalence relations of $R$ so again symmetric.

For transitivity we have to consider $(x,y)$ in some finite such chain (say length $n$) and $(y,z)$ in another such chain (length $m$) and perhaps we can reason that $(x,z)$ is in some $n+m$ length "composition chain" (or one shorter or longer), depending on the last $\theta$ in the chain perhaps?

I'd say it's not about how unions commute with compositions but a case by case proof of the different cases provided by the union..

Comment: It might be helpful to notice that as expressed in this Question, the union is a *nested union* of equivalence relations, which simplifies the verification.

Comment: @hardmath I dont think the relational products are necessarily equivalence relations themselves (they are reflexive, but not symmetric or transivitve generally). So what you stated is not true in my opinion.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Thank you, but I don´t see how the transitivity is shown, for example if the first chain endes with $\theta_2$ and the second starts again with $\theta_1$. Then we have $(c,y) \in \theta_2$ for some $c$ and $(y,d) \in \theta_1$ for some $d$. But so what

Comment: @TerezaTizkova try another approach then. I was just making suggestions not claiming that it worked.